# How can i format the post data from client in .net core mvc web api controller without [FromBody]

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

How can I format the post data from client in .net core MVC web API controller without [FromBody]

I tried this in Startup.cs

```
 services.AddMvc()
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
                    new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            });
```

but i can't run

I used this in Asp.Net MVC web API projects in WepApiConfig.cs

```
var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

but I can't find in the same feature in .net core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send the request body as `x-www-form-urlencoded`, i.e. the familiar query string format (`foo=bar&bar=baz`). If you're sending JSON, you *must* use `FromBody`.

Comment: I'm sending JSON. I don't want to use FromBody. I want to manage from one place. Do not have a solution like Asp.net MVC.

Comment: You *can't*. JSON requires `FromBody`. Period. What is the problem with using `FromBody` anyways?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will use the request body as x-www-form-urlencoded.